# Modificar post_max_size mientras se este ejecuntando el metodo post

Tags: php

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Con el uso de la función `ini_set` , podemos modificar  los valores por defecto configurados en el intéprete `PHP` mientras que el script se esté ejecutando, podemos cambiar el tamaño permitido para el método `post`?

Estoy tratando de cambiar `post_max_size` usando `ini_set()`, pero no funciona. Después de algunas investigaciones, llegué a la conclusión de que esto se debe al momento en que se aplica `post_max_size`.

Entonces, qué hacer para cambiar post_max_size sin tener que editar manualmente `php.ini` ni `.htaccess`

Mi secuencia de comandos es un formulario de carga y debe manejar archivos grandes, y solo quiero que se apliquen estas configuraciones, no todas las demás secuencias de comandos.

Comment: sin acceso al .ini o .htaccess lo que se usa es un "chunk uploader" es decir un subidor por partes, [plupload](https://www.plupload.com/) es (2022) usado bastante; trae [ejemplos en php](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/tree/master/examples). si usas composer tambien hay [varios disponibles](https://www.google.com/search?q=composer+chunk+upload) que generalmente los ves en tutoriales de laravel

Comment: todo depende de tu backend y frontend; si no puedes trabajar con `php.ini` o `.htaccess`, te pediria un justificacion por que no puedes usarlos, tambien te pediria que nos muestres una cpatura completa del output de `phpinfo()` con tal de conocer el ambiente de desarrollo que estas utilizando y validar que respuesta alternativa te podemos dar...

Comment: Actualmete tengo esto en el archivo .htaccess en laravel 9:      #AUMENTAMOS EL LIMITE DE LA MEMORIA PARA QUE PHP SAQUE EL REPORTE SIN DIFICULTA.
    php_value memory_limit 10240M
    php_value max_execution_time 10000
    php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
    php_value post_max_size 500M
    php_value max_input_time 10000
    php_value zlib.output_compression On

Comment: no se entiende en tu comentario; actualiza el post con la informacion y trabajamos sobre ello. ok